# Returning a list containing a mix of null items and non-null items

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an API endpoint which takes in a list of requests and returns a list objects. What I want is get an empty list sent to the method caller if the results list contains just one item and the item is null. Otherwise, the list should return all the items, with those which are null having the request Id passed on and those which have data displaying the filled in data together with their request Id.

This is the method I currently have:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Model>?> Details(IEnumerable<Params> requests)
{
    var results = new List<Model>();

    foreach (var request in requests)
    {
        var result = await Method1Async(request);

        if (results.Any && result == null)
        {
            results.Add(new Model { Id = request.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(result);
        }
    }
    
    return results.All(x => x == null) ? Enumerable.Empty<Model>() : results;
}
```

Say I send a request list having the following, with `cd123` as an invalid item code:

```
[
{
"Id": 1,
"ItemCode" : "cd123" 
},
{
"Id": 2,
"ItemCode" : "cd456" 
}
]
```

What I expect to have is:

```
[
{
"Id": 1,
"ItemCode" : null,
"ProductName": null,
"ProductDate": null 
},
{
"Id": 2,
"ItemCode" : "cd456",
"ProductName": Topaz everlife,
"ProductDate": 2023-05-12
}
]
```

But what I get presently is this:

```
[
{
null
},
{
"Id": 2,
"ItemCode" : "cd456",
"ProductName": Topaz everlife,
"ProductDate": 2023-05-12
}
]
```

What logic am I missing on the conditions to get the expected behaviors?

Comment: `But what I get presently is this:` this JSON is not valid. What exactly is the output? My guess is it should be `[null, { ... }]` right?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand when you say the JSON isn't valid. What I expect if I have more than one item in the list is to return the `Id` for all the items, with every property null for what could not be found in the database and data filled in for what could be found. It is the reason I'm expecting this: `[{"Id": 1,"ItemCode" : null,"ProductName": null,"ProductDate": null },{"Id": 2,"ItemCode" : "cd456","ProductName": Topaz everlife,
"ProductDate": 2023-05-12}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found an issue with your code but it's in no way produce something like the JSON you have in your question.

```cs
        if (results.Any() && result == null)
        {
            results.Add(new Model { Id = request.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(result);
        }
```

If your first request is not `null`, all good. Then if the 2nd item onwards is `null`, it cannot satisfy the `if` condition and instead you would add a `null` to your `results`. If I understand your goal correctly, the `if` should be:

```cs
        if (result == null)
        {
            results.Add(new Model { Id = request.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(result);
        }
```

And you should separate the 1 item logic at the beginning instead.

This demo works for me:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintModels(GetDetails([6, 1]));
        PrintModels(GetDetails([6]));
        PrintModels(GetDetails([4, 5, 6]));
    }
    
    static void PrintModels(IEnumerable<Model> models)
    {
        if (!models.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No item");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(models));
    }

    static IEnumerable<Model> GetDetails(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        var results = new List<Model>();

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            // Simulate 5 first items
            results.Add(id switch
            {
                < 6 => new() { Id = id, ItemCode = "Id: " + id },
                _ => new() { Id = id, }
            });
        }

        return results.All(q => q.ItemCode is null) ?
            Enumerable.Empty<Model>() :
            results;
    }

    class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? ItemCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get your point. When you say `separate the 1 item logic at the beginning instead`, do you mean adding a first condition before the two others, which will resemble something like: `if(results.Count ==1 && results[0] == null){return Enumerable.Empty<Model>()}` ?

Comment: @NiceKloe Yeah something like that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for spotting out the issue in the code. Your answer indeed meets one of the requirements (when there are more than one item in the list, all of them are returned, with null for properties having no data and data filled in for properties having them). Nonetheless, the first requirement is still missing. With the condition I provided in my previous comment, I don't succeed in getting an empty list when there is only one null item in the list. Any other idea of yours would be appreciated.

Comment: @NiceKloe check my updated code which I used to try to reproduce the issue,